# Abstract Calendar returning null

Tags: java, oop, calendar, abstract

I am trying to get an abstract Calendar to get dates for different timespans. I got the Abstract Calendar class, where I define a new Calendar and two methods.

```
public abstract class AbstractThreshold {

private Calendar cal;

public abstract Calendar getStartDate();
public abstract Calendar getEndDate();
public abstract void calculateThreshold();

protected void DateThreshold(final Date date) {
    this.cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    this.cal.setTime(date);
}

protected Calendar getInitial() {
    return (Calendar) this.cal.clone();
}
```

}

Then the class for a timespan of a month

```
public class MonthThreshold extends AbstractThreshold{

@Override
public Calendar getStartDate() {
    final Calendar cal = super.getInitial();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    return (Calendar) cal;
}

@Override
public Calendar getEndDate() {
    final Calendar cal = super.getInitial();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    return (Calendar) cal;
}

@Override
public void calculateThreshold() {

}
```

}

At last I am calling those in my main class of my programm.

```
MonthThreshold mt = new MonthThreshold();
firstTime = unparsedDate.format(mt.getStartDate());
secondTime = unparsedDate.format(mt.getEndDate());
```

The programm returns a null at the MonthThreshold class at the point

```
final Calendar cal = super.getInitial();
```

I am new to programming and abstract programming still hits me hard...what did I wrong and what do I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the calendar in the void DateThreshold() method  and on where you are calling this DateThreshold. You are calling cal.getInitial() to get the clone of Calendar. Obviously calendar is not initalized in getInitial(). Make use of DateTHreshod() to get the calendar instance.

```
protected Calendar getInitial() {
        this.cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.cal.setTime(new Date());
        return (Calendar) this.cal.clone();
    }
```

Here i have pasted code to avoid NPE. For me it's not giving NPE. But the logic is upto you.

Comment: So I have to initialize a variable called date in my Month Treshold class? But then they want the DateThreshold to return a Calendar, not a Date

Comment: Nowhere you are using DateThreshold() method and you are intializing an calendar there. Either intialize the calendar in getinitial() method or just make use of DateThreshold() method.

Comment: So I could get rid of the DateThreshold, initialize in getInitial like protected Calendar getInitial(Date date) {
  this.cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  this.cal.setTime(date);
  return (Calendar) this.cal.clone();
 } ?

Comment: yes. you can get rid off. But you have to take care of your logic. That depends on your application!

Comment: All code that is needed at that point is posted above. I switched the both lines this.cal = Calendar.getInstance(); and this.cal.setTime(date); to the getInitial without changing anything, yet there is still the Nullpointer. I am sorry that I seem stupid, but this kind of programming is new to me

Comment: The only problem left is that Eclipse does not accept the parameters from getInitial. super.getInitial(Date date) etc does not work

Comment: Found the mistake, nvm, nothing to do with parameters. The problem now is when I fillm the variable it is still null, firstTime = unparsedDate.format(mt.getStartDate());